# Can I get a recording of every data that was in a cell in excel (from a time that I choose)

Tags: excel, vba

I am programming a chess game and I thought it would be cool if the user could watch the game after it happened, or even enter a game of his own.
the way my chess game works is there are two cells: one where the user enters the square of the piece he want to move, and one where the user enters where he want the piece to be moved to.
I thought that maybe if I could see the history of a cell, I could run a program that is do the moves without checking if they are legal (because he wouldn't have been able to play them if they weren't).
Is there a way to check a cell history? or at least save it somehow and delete when a new game starts?

Comment: Take a look at the Worksheet's Change event. You can store the value of every change that happens in those cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private isRunning As Boolean
Private moves As New Collection

Private Sub start_button_Click()
    isRunning = True
End Sub

Private Sub stop_button_Click()
    isRunning = False
    Dim val As Variant
    For Each val In moves
        Debug.Print val
    Next val
    Set moves = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If isRunning Then
        moves.Add Target.Address & " " & Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

> Then I wrote inside the following cells:
>
> [image]
>
> Which yielded the following result:
>
> [image]

Comment: Where does is write what it has recoreded?

Comment: Into the Immediate window - *console* - (`Ctrl+G`) via the `Debug.Print` command. But I mean you can print the results in any way you want - eg. `MsgBox(val)` or even into your worksheet via a simple `for` loop

Comment: This is one of the problems with answering broad questions on SO. The follow-up questions keep on coming :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Couldn't have described my sentiment better. Honestly, after reading the follow-up, I'm kind of afraid OP won't even understand why or how the code works :/  - I guess lack of code in the original question was a red flag already

Comment: @Rawrplus I understand you concern, but I won't ever use a code without understanding it first. when i write a program I want to be able to manipulate the code in however I want to use it. while yes, I don't understand the code yet, as most of it are new to me since I'm new to VBA, I am reading online about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yoni, you can use a *Collection* in a *[Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement)* statement. This means in the life of your Application, and the code doesn't Stop (debug, then manually stopped from you), you can retain information for as much memory as you want to use ([variable-length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) uses 10 bytes + 1*Len(string) per byte - nothing crazy for your goal).

The below code records the Activecell address, every time you activate another cell:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub WorkSheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static addresses As New Collection

    addresses.Add ActiveCell.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: And then when I want ti access the record how do I do it?

Comment: This is one of the problems with answering broad questions on SO. The follow-up questions keep on coming :)

Comment: Yoni,you can use the _FileSystemObject_ object library to create a text file first, then, append to it with each new entry. Or, you can loop all the values into a _MsgBox_ by concatenating one big string - `myString = myString & vbnewline & collectionItem.` Or, you can build a UserForm to create labels at runtime, and increasing the ScrollHeight along with it.... many different possibilities.